# How to use assertion in destructuring syntax?

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, how can I use assertion in destructuring?

```
type StringOrNumber = string | number

const obj = {
  foo: 123 as StringOrNumber
}

const { foo } = obj
```

I didn't find a convenient way to add `number` type assertion on const `foo`. Two workarounds are:

```
// A:
const { foo } = obj as { foo: number }

// B:
const { foo: foo2 } = obj

const foo = <number>foo2
```

The first is a burden to rewrite the `obj`'s type when its type is nested and complicated. The second seems weird. I'm assuming such a syntax like:

```
const { <number>foo } = obj
```

can absolutely help us asserting the type from nested and complicated destructuring.

Comment: `const { foo: number } = obj;`?

Comment: That would not work, it would take the value of `foo` and assign it to the variable `number`

Comment: I had the same issue and calling foo as `Number(foo)` did the trick for me as a way to tell TS the output was a number.

Comment: Another workaround could be `const foo = obj.foo as number`

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#object-destructuring), there is no way for casting the type right when destructuring. Apparently, there are no workarounds other than those that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are no possible way to do type assertion in destructuring objects or arrays.

But here are an alternative you can try.

```
const { foo, bar } = data;
const baz = foo as string;

// You can use string methods here.
console.log(baz.split(" "));
```